# Top and right axes labels in matplotlib pyplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib/pyplot plot that appears as I want, in that the axes show the required range of values from -1 to +1 on both the x and y axes. I have labelled the x and y axes. However I also wish to label the right-hand vertical axis with the text "Thinking" and the top axis with the text "Extraversion".

I have looked at the matplotlib documentation but can't get my code to execute using set_xlabel and set_ylabel. I have commented these lines out in my code so my code runs for now - but hopefully the comments will make it clear enough what I am trying to do.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w = 6
h = 6
d = 70
plt.figure(figsize=(w, h), dpi=d)
x = [-0.34,-0.155,0.845,0.66,-0.34]
y = [0.76,0.24,-0.265,0.735,0.76,]
 
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlim(-1,1)
plt.ylim(-1,1)
plt.xlabel("Intraverted")
plt.ylabel("Feeling")
#secax = plt.secondary_xaxis('top')
#secax.set_xlabel('Extraverted')
#secay = plt.secondary_xaxis('right')
#secay.set_ylabel('Thinking')
#plt.show()
plt.savefig("out.png")
```

Comment: [`.secondary_xaxis`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_xaxis.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_xaxis) is an axis function and cannot be directly used with pyplot. I suggest getting familiar with the differences between [pyplot and object oriented axis programming](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/). They are sometimes similar in function name (e.g., `plt.plot()` and `ax.plot()`) but not equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mr. T pointed out, there is no `plt.secondary_xaxis` method so you need the axes object

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6), constrained_layout=True, dpi=70)
x = [-0.34,-0.155,0.845,0.66,-0.34]
y = [0.76,0.24,-0.265,0.735,0.76,]
 
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlim(-1,1)
plt.ylim(-1,1)
plt.xlabel("Intraverted")
plt.ylabel("Feeling")
secax = plt.gca().secondary_xaxis('top')
secax.set_xlabel('Extraverted')
secay = plt.gca().secondary_yaxis('right')
secay.set_ylabel('Thinking')
#plt.show()
plt.savefig("out.png")
```

[image]

Better, would be just to create the axes object from the start:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(w, h), constrained_layout=True, dpi=d)
...
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
...
secax = ax.secondary_xaxis('top')
...
fig.savefig("out.png")
```

Further note the use of `constrained_layout=True` to make the secondary yaxis label fit on the figure.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it with plt.subplots()

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w = 6
h = 6
d = 70
plt.figure(figsize=(w, h), dpi=d)
x = [-0.34,-0.155,0.845,0.66,-0.34]
y = [0.76,0.24,-0.265,0.735,0.76,]

fig , ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.plot(x, y)


plt.xlim(-1,1)
plt.ylim(-1,1)
plt.xlabel("Intraverted")
plt.ylabel("Feeling")


ax2 = ax1.twinx()
plt.ylabel('right corner')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).